# Terraform wait until execution of user_data then make an image to autoscale?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloud, devops, aws-auto-scaling

I am making a [scalable service](https://github.com/ashraf-minhaj/AWS-AutoScale-MediaProcessor) using AWS EC2, AutoScale Groups, SQS and CloudWatch Alarm using Terraform with `user_data` to set things up. I am using a `aws_launch_template` and scaling using autoscale.

It works, but for every new instances it runs user_data again and that takes a lot of time. The only workaround to this is making `machine image` from my instance. But terraform does not know if the user_data has executed or not.

I am thinking of creating an instance, then making an image from it using terraform then use that as template to autoscale. Found [this post](https://rpadovani.com/terraform-cloudinit) but not so clear.

I am trying this code -

```
resource "aws_ssm_document" "cloud_init_wait" {
  name = "cloud-init-wait"
  document_type = "Command"
  document_format = "YAML"
  content = <<-DOC
    schemaVersion: '2.2'
    description: Wait for cloud init to finish
    mainSteps:
    - action: aws:runShellScript
      name: StopOnLinux
      precondition:
        StringEquals:
        - platformType
        - Linux
      inputs:
        runCommand:
        - cloud-init status --wait
    DOC
}


resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = var.instance_ami
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name              = "${var.ssh_key}"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

    command = <<-EOF
    set -Ee -o pipefail
    export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${var.aws_region}

    command_id=$(aws ssm send-command --document-name ${aws_ssm_document.cloud_init_wait.arn} --instance-ids ${self.id} --output text --query "Command.CommandId")
    if ! aws ssm wait command-executed --command-id $command_id --instance-id ${self.id}; then
      echo "Failed to start services on instance ${self.id}!";
      echo "stdout:";
      aws ssm get-command-invocation --command-id $command_id --instance-id ${self.id} --query StandardOutputContent;
      echo "stderr:";
      aws ssm get-command-invocation --command-id $command_id --instance-id ${self.id} --query StandardErrorContent;
      exit 1;
    fi;
    echo "Services started successfully on the new instance with id ${self.id}!"

    EOF
  }
}
```

I am having this error:

```
 exit status 254. Output: 
│ An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation: Instances [[i-05b9f087e8d7dd7xx]] not in a
│ valid state for account 669201380121
```

Any idea on how we can make terraform wait until user data ran then make an image to autoscale?

Comment: Its not possible unless you develop your own fully custom solution.

Comment: hm... so now I made an Image using the console and using that as a template to autoscale.

Comment: @Marcin it's possible with Packer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Manual Image Creation (Old answer)**

> scroll down for automated solution with Packer

It might be possible but it seemed harder.
So I first

1. made an instance from the console
2. then installed some dependencies
3. After that made an image
4. used the image id to create an ec2 instance launch_template
5. use user_data to provision source code to process (depending on your need).

Now whenever my autoscale group creates instances I have my dependencies installed.  It's much faster now.

```
locals {
  provision_config= <<-END
    #cloud-config
    ${jsonencode({
      write_files = [
        {
          path        = "/root/src/main.py"
          permissions = "0644"
          encoding    = "b64"
          content     = filebase64("../src/main.py")
        },
      ]
    })}
  END
}

data "cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip                = false
  base64_encode       = true

  part {
    content_type      = "text/cloud-config"
    filename          = "cloud-config_provision.yaml"
    content           = local.provision_config
    }

  part {
    content_type      = "text/x-shellscript"
    filename          = "run_src.sh"
    content           = <<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      cd /root
      mkdir tmp
      mkdir tmp/origin
      mkdir tmp/converted
      mkdir tmp/packaged
      
      pip3 install boto3
      pip3 install ec2-metadata
      cd src

      python3 main.py

    EOF
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "instance_profile" {
  name                  = "${local.resource_component}-profile"
  role                  = "${aws_iam_role.ec2_role.name}"
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "machine_template" {
  name                  = "${local.resource_component}-template" 
  image_id              = "${var.instance_ami}"
  instance_type         = "${var.instance_type}"
  key_name              = "${var.ssh_key}"
  user_data             = "${data.cloudinit_config.config.rendered}"

  iam_instance_profile {
    name                = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.instance_profile.name}"
  }

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type       = "instance"
    tags = {
      Name              = "${local.resource_component}-child"
      Source            = "Autoscaling"
    } 
  }

  monitoring {
    enabled             = true
  }

  instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = "terminate"
}
```

**Automated Image Creation with [Packer by HCL](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/tutorials) (Edited Answer)**

I am making AMI before `terraform plan`, and automated the system using a shell script, you can [find my solution here](https://github.com/ashraf-minhaj/AWS-IaCs-with-Terraform/tree/main/1012%20packer).
I found this as the best of all the ways, with autoscale it's even faster since I don't have to provision things again and again. There's also limitation for `user_data` which this solution solves easily.